# How do I hide a button in php when metabox is empty?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want the button hide when it is empty remain unfortunately only the HTML before, even though the button is already empty, how can I rewrite the code so the button is hidden? I posted more details maybe someone can help me me

```
 function cspm_infobox_content(){

        $post_id = esc_attr($_POST['post_id']);
        $infobox_type = esc_attr($_POST['infobox_type']);
        $map_id = esc_attr($_POST['map_id']);
        $status = esc_attr($_POST['status']);
        $carousel = esc_attr($_POST['carousel']);
        $telnr = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'telnr', true );
        $telnr1 = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'telnr1', true );
        $email = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'email', true );
        $hane = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'hane', true );
        $marte = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'marte', true );
        $merkure = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'merkure', true );
        $enjte = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'enjte', true );
        $premte = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'premte', true );
        $shtune = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'shtune', true );
        $djele = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'djele', true );
        $shteti = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'shteti', true );
        $qyteti = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'qyteti', true );
        $rajoni = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'rajoni', true );
        $rruganr = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'rruganr', true );

        $no_title = array(); // Infoboxes to display with no title
        $no_link = array(); // Infobox to display whit no link
        $no_description = array('square_bubble', 'rounded_bubble', 'cspm_type2', 'cspm_type3', 'cspm_type4'); // Infoboxes to display with no description
        $no_image = array('cspm_type4'); // Infoboxes to display with no image



        if(!in_array($infobox_type, $no_title)) $item_title = apply_filters('cspm_custom_infobox_title', stripslashes_deep($this->cspm_items_title($post_id, $this->items_title)), $post_id); 
        if(!in_array($infobox_type, $no_description)) $item_description = apply_filters('cspm_custom_infobox_description', stripslashes_deep($this->cspm_items_details($post_id, $this->items_details)), $post_id);
        if(!in_array($infobox_type, $no_link)) $the_permalink = $this->cspm_get_permalink($post_id);

        if(!in_array($infobox_type, $no_image)){

            if($infobox_type == 'square_bubble' || $infobox_type == 'rounded_bubble')
                $parameter = array( 'style' => "width:50px; height:50px;" );
            elseif($infobox_type == 'cspm_type1')
                $parameter = array( 'style' => "width:100px; height:80px;" );
            elseif($infobox_type == 'cspm_type2')
                $parameter = array();
            elseif($infobox_type == 'cspm_type3' || $infobox_type == 'cspm_type5')
                $parameter = array( 'style' => "width:60px; height:60px;" );
            elseif($infobox_type == 'cspm_type4')
                $parameter = array();

            if($infobox_type == 'square_bubble' || $infobox_type == 'rounded_bubble'){
                $infobox_thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'cspacing-marker-thumbnail', $parameter);
            }elseif($infobox_type == 'cspm_type1'){
                $infobox_thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'cspacing-infobox1-thumbnail', $parameter);
            }else $infobox_thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'cspacing-horizontal-thumbnail', $parameter);

            if(empty($infobox_thumb))
                $infobox_thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'cspacing-horizontal-thumbnail', $parameter);

        }

        $post_thumbnail = apply_filters('cspm_infobox_thumb', $infobox_thumb, $post_id, $infobox_type, $parameter);

        $this->infobox_external_link = $this->cspm_get_setting('infoboxsettings', 'infobox_external_link', 'same_window');

        $target = ($this->infobox_external_link == 'new_window') ? ' target="_blank"' : ''; 
        $the_post_link = ($this->infobox_external_link == 'disable') ? $item_title : '<a href="'.$the_permalink.'" title="'.$item_title.'"'.$target.'>'.$item_title.'</a>'; 

        $output = '';

        $output .= '<div class="cspm_infobox_content_container '.$status.' infobox_'.$map_id.' '.$infobox_type.'" data-map-id="'.$map_id.'" data-post-id="'.$post_id.'" data-show-carousel="'.$carousel.'">';

            if($infobox_type == 'square_bubble' || $infobox_type == 'rounded_bubble'){

                $output .= '<div class="cspm_infobox_img">';
                    $output .= ($this->infobox_external_link != 'disable') ? '<a href="'.$the_permalink.'" title="'.$item_title.'"'.$target.'>'.$post_thumbnail.'</a>' : $post_thumbnail;
                $output .= '</div>';
                $output .= '<div class="cspm_arrow_down '.$infobox_type.'"></div>';

            }elseif($infobox_type == 'cspm_type1'){

                $output .= '<div class="cspm_infobox_img">'.$post_thumbnail.'</div>';
                $output .= '<div class="cspm_infobox_content">';
                    $output .= '<div class="title">'.$the_post_link.'</div>';
                    $output .= '<div class="description">'.$item_description.'</div>';
                $output .= '</div>';
                $output .= '<div style="clear:both"></div>';
                $output .= '<div class="cspm_arrow_down"></div>';

            }elseif($infobox_type == 'cspm_type2'){

                $output .= '<div class="cspm_infobox_img">'.$post_thumbnail.'</div>';
                $output .= '<div class="cspm_infobox_content">';
                    $output .= '<div class="title">'.$the_post_link.'</div>';
                $output .= '</div>';
                $output .= '<div class="cspm_arrow_down"></div>';

            }elseif($infobox_type == 'cspm_type3'){

                $output .= '<div class="cspm_infobox_img">'.$post_thumbnail.'</div>';
                $output .= '<div class="cspm_infobox_content">';
                    $output .= '<div class="title">'.$the_post_link.'</div>';
                $output .= '</div>';
                $output .= '<div class="cspm_arrow_down"></div>';

            }elseif($infobox_type == 'cspm_type4'){

                $output .= '<div class="cspm_infobox_content">';
                    $output .= '<div class="title">'.$the_post_link.'</div>';
                $output .= '</div>';
                $output .= '<div class="cspm_arrow_down"></div>';

            /**
             * @since 2.7 */

            }elseif($infobox_type == 'cspm_type5'){

                $output .= '<div class="cspm_infobox_content">';
                    $output .= '<div>';
                        $output .= '<div class="cspm_infobox_img">'.$post_thumbnail.'</div>';
                        $output .= '<div class="title">'.$the_post_link.'</div>';
                        $output .= '<div class="telnr"><a class="wm-button color-read" href="tel:'.$telnr.'"><img src="http://porosija.com/pinfo/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Phone-18-18-dimenzionet.png" height="18" width="18"></a>';
                        $output .= '<a class="wm-button color-read telnr1" style="left: 10px;" href="tel:'.$telnr1.'"><img src="http://porosija.com/pinfo/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Phone-18-18-dimenzionet.png" height="18" width="18"></a>';
                        $output .= '<a class="wm-button color-blue email" style="left: 20px;" href="mailto:'.$email.'?Subject=Un%20jam%20informuar%20për%20ju%20nga%20www.porosija.com&nbsp;"><img src="http://porosija.com/pinfo/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/email-ico.png" height="18" width="18"></a></div>';
```

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding the question... "remain"?  Maybe rephrase a bit, I can try and clean up the grammar and what not if I get the gist.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question. If you want to hide a button from the server (e.g., by using php) I guess you need to receive some kind of feedback from the client, for example by submitting a form, and after you check, if some variable is empty then do not produce html code for showing the button. Now, another possibility is hiding the button using Javascript; in this case you need to bind an event to certain field (for example) and when the user writes something in it you make the button appear.

First case example:

PHP:

```
$myvar = $_GET['myvar_from_form'];
$html = '...';

if(isset($myvvar)){
    $html = '<button>...</button>';
}
```

Second case example:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="myvar" />
<button style="display: none;">Button</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('input', function(){
    document.querySelector('button').style.display = '';
    console.log('input changed to: ', input.value);
});
```

You may also want to validate when the new input's value is empty.

Comment: If this answers your question, you should mark it as the answer.

Comment: In the beginning I thought it worked, but it was an error message

Comment: Take into account that the answer contains only dummy code. If you require help with your implementation, you may modify the question, so that we can know what the problem is.

Comment: when I try something to add, for example, if (! empty or something like if (isset ($ myvvar)) {work .I do not post again more code because as ausiht

Comment: the code that I want to hide when there is no value there is at the bottom

if it were possible even an ID name if I there something gentler or under the somewhat inflict breaks the starting and working
  no more

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the conversation in here, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your comment @TonTonii. Please re-think your question and clean up your code for us to understand.